# How to change the layout with different markup when device rotation?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments

### Description

I have one activity **in the vertical orinentation** with two tabs (*TabLayout*) and fragments, which change with *Viewpager*.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        // Assign created adapter to viewPager
        viewPager.setAdapter(new TabsExamplePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        // This method setup all required method for TabLayout with Viewpager
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }

    public class TabsExamplePagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        // As we are implementing two tabs
        private static final int NUM_ITEMS = 2;

        public TabsExamplePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        // For each tab different fragment is returned
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return new TabOneFragment();
                case 1:
                    return new TabTwoFragment();
                default:
                    return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return NUM_ITEMS;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) { 
            return "Tab " + (position + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:tabTextColor="#ffffff"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="#fbff3a"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="#fbff3a"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="5dp"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabMaxWidth="0dp" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

In each tabs i have for one fragments.

**TabOneFragment.java** (TabTwoFragment is similar ):

```
public class TabOneFragment extends Fragment {

    // Required empty public constructor
    public TabOneFragment() { }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab_one, container, false);
    }
}
```

**fragment_one_tab.xml** (fragment_one_tab.xml is similar)

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="innovatecode.com.tabexample.TabOneFragment">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:text="@string/tab_one" />

</FrameLayout>
```

And i have simply result:

[image]

### My problem

When my device is rotated to **the horizontal position**, I want to get the following result:
[image]

I create xml for horizontal markup (*land*):

**active_main.xml** (land)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

     <FrameLayout 
            android:id="@+id/fragment_left"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

      <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_right"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

But I don't know **how to change my code** to get this result. I'm not very strong in working with fragments.

Comment: Put your layout files in `res/layout-land`.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, yes, i know it. Android Studio did that automatically. That's not the problem.

Answer (score 1):

First, you can improve your landscape layout by adding your fragments directly to the layout file (under "res/layout-land"):

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

     <fragment
            android:name="innovatecode.com.tabexample.TabOneFragment"
            android:id="@+id/fragment_left"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

      <fragment
            android:name="innovatecode.com.tabexample.TabTwoFragment"
            android:id="@+id/fragment_right"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

You can read move on the topic [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html#AddInLayout).

For the code part, you could make use of distinct features of your landscape and portrait layouts to switch between the corresponding logic in code. For example:

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (findViewById(R.id.tab_layout) != null) {
            setUpPortraitLayout();
        } else {
            setUpLandscapeLayout();
        }
    }

    private void setUpPortraitLayout() {
        ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.pager);
        // Assign created adapter to viewPager
        viewPager.setAdapter(new TabsExamplePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));

        TabLayout tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        // This method setup all required method for TabLayout with Viewpager
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }

    private void setUpLandscapeLayout() {
        // Note: with the layout definition suggested above you don't
        // need any manual processing to set-up your layout for landscape
        // but you still may have some extra set-up (initial binding, etc).
        tabOneFragment = (TabOneFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_left);
        tabTwoFragment = (TabTwoFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_right);
        // ...
    }
}
```

You can pass saved parameters to your fragments via "[setArguments()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#setArguments(android.os.Bundle))" method. Alternatively consider using "onSaveInstanceState()" methods of your fragments (as opposed to activity, which you use now).

**Alternative approach**: dynamically add fragments in both landscape and portrait cases. It is based on your code. I think some aspects are arguable (I may be wrong), but changing direction would mean rewriting the whole thing. But it should work eventually.

res/layout-land/active_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

     <FrameLayout 
            android:id="@+id/fragment_left"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

      <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_right"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java (based off the code you shared via gist)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Fragment tabOneFragment;
    private Fragment tabTwoFragment;

    private ViewPager viewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            //Restore the fragment's instance
            tabOneFragment = (TabOneFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().getFragment(
                    savedInstanceState, "tabOneFragment");
            tabTwoFragment = (TabTwoFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().getFragment(
                    savedInstanceState, "tabTwoFragment");
        } else {
            tabOneFragment = new TabOneFragment();
            tabTwoFragment = new TabTwoFragment();
        }

        if (findViewById(R.id.tab_layout) != null) {
            setUpPortraitLayout();
        } else {
            setUpLandscapeLayout();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        getSupportFragmentManager().putFragment(outState, "tabOneFragment", tabOneFragment);
        getSupportFragmentManager().putFragment(outState, "tabTwoFragment", tabTwoFragment);
    }

    private void setUpPortraitLayout() {
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        // Assign created adapter to viewPager
        viewPager.setAdapter(new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        // This method setup all required method for TabLayout with Viewpager
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }

    private void setUpLandscapeLayout() { 
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_left, tabOneFragment);
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_right, tabTwoFragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
    }

    private class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        // As we are implementing two tabs
        private static final int NUM_ITEMS = 2;

        public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
            super(fragmentManager);
        }

        @Override
        // For each tab different fragment is returned
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return tabOneFragment;

                case 1:
                    return tabTwoFragment;

                default:
                    throw new IllegalStateException("Invalid tab index");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() { return NUM_ITEMS; }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {  return "Tab " + (position + 1); }

        // NOTE: I think you do not really need to override "instantiateItem()", therefore I removed it.
    }
}
```

Comment: Ohh, Alexsander, thank you for answer. But, if use your method, how about saving and passing data beetwen changed device orientation ?

Comment: In a nutshell, you can override "onSaveInstanceState()" in your activity to save the necessary custom data before the old activity is destroyed. This data will be passed into your "onCreate()" method ("savedInstanceState" parameter) and you can forward it to your set-up methods.

Comment: Alexander, i have update your code for replace fragment when device rotation, but i have problem with `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cant change container ID of fragment TabOneFragment...`. Can look at [my code](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/cc4a373bcc1717e6614816c03b5fab4f), please ?

Comment: Yes, right. The problem is you are trying to manually add you fragments to the landscape layout, while you no longer need to (see the note in `setUpLandscapeLayout()` method above) and you actually cannot replace the fragment in this case - this is why you get exception. Though, I've forgotten to add the fragment class names to the layout definition  - I'll update my answer now. I'll also update the source part with the proper way of getting references to inflated fragments, shall you need make some calls on those guys.

Comment: Alexander, Thank you for your help. Can I ask you more on Skype or another messanger?

Comment: Ohh my God... If i use `tabOneFragment = (TabOneFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_left);` how showing in your code, i haven't exception, but my **LandscapeLayout** have default result. When i use "old" fragments with `onSaveInstanceState()` i have `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cant change container ID of fragment TabOneFragment...` again((

Comment: I've added an alternative approach based on your code. Try it out - it should work.

Comment: Maybe it's some kind of curse, but  i have `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cant change container ID of fragment TabOneFragment...` again((( Can i send you my all project in the Skype or other messenger?(

Comment: [Full project.](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1H916AQYl1Fph7iEzlRn99gfqElWLr2em) Maybe I don't see what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I had a look.. it is getting bumpy with fragments. :/ As far as I understand the problem is when you save the fragment, its "mContainerId" (the id of the view it is added to via transition) is save as a part of its state. When the fragment is being added to the view pager, the container id is being checked against the new "host view" and the check fails. I've tried a few things, but at the moment I have no idea how to solve it, sorry. If I happen to come up with some solution, I'll let you know.
I recommend you to look for similar topics - I saw a few, but didn't have time to read in details.

Comment: Also, consider using view groups instead of fragments, it **could** make your life a bit easier.

Comment: Can you write me in the skype please?  will be Very grateful for the help! Because it's project very importent for me.

Comment: Sorry, Tomas, but I am not available for chat.

Comment: Well, write to me here.